# FOR, IF and SET all are not working together

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) DO (  
IF %%A EQU 1 (  
SET CHOICE1=ABC  
ECHO CHOICE1=%CHOICE1%  
)  
)
```

Output:

```
CHOICE1=
```

Why is `CHOICE1` not getting set?

Answer (score 0):

When using `EnableDelayedExpansion` you must also use `!` around variables you want to delay expanding.

Therefore, instead of `%CHOICE1%` you must use `!CHOICE1!`.